# Creating multiple copies of workbook with different subset of data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with master data. I need to create copies of the master data into multiple workbook with different sets of data. Since the file has data validation linked to other sheets in the workbook copying the content from worksheet is not working.

```
Set SourceWorkBK = Workbooks.Open(Path_SourceWorkBK)<br>
Set NewWorKBK = SourceWorkBK
```

Any changes I make to the `NewWorKBK` is impacting the `SourceWorkBK`
I need to make new copies of `SourceWorkBK` after deleting some data into `NewWorKBK` without impacting the `SourceWorkBK`.

Comment: Can you post an example of the change

Answer (score 0):

Your code creates two variables and points them to the same object. What you want to do is save your workbook under a different name, and then start deleting data

```
Set SourceWorkBK = Workbooks.Open(Path_SourceWorkBK)
SourceWorkBK.SaveAs SourceWorkBK.Path & "fred.xls"
```

will create a copy of SourceWorkBK in the same folder, under the name fred.

Comment: Appreciate your help.Once i save this and close the workbook. I need to open the source workbook again to create 2nd set of data. Lets say My source workbook has details of fruits. I want to create separate workbook for each fruits. is it possible to do this without closing and reopening the source file.

Comment: It would be easier to put your program code in a separate workbook. That code could then repeatedly open the master file and save it under different names. It would be a lot easier if you just wanted to copy a single sheet - the requirement to copy the whole workbook makes this much harder.